# How to get value of ForeignKey in views.py?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have below models.py and views.py in Django(This is only a example). How can i print the value of ForeignKey in views.py?

models.py

```
class student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.ForeignKey(tell,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class tell(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.phone_number
```

views.py

```
phones =  student.objects.values('phone_number')
phone =   list(phones)
for ob in phone:
   print(ob)
```

This prints only `id` but i want the value of foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the (many) reasons *not* to use [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values): it erodes the model logical layer of a Django model.

You can work with:

```
tell.objects.filter(student__isnull=False)
```

this will retrieve all `tell` ojects that have at least a related `Student`.

You can also use [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to select the telephone number while retrieving the `student`s, and thus avoid an *N+1 problem*:

```
students = student.objects.select_related('phone_number'):
for stud in students:
    print(stud.phone_number)
```

If you really want to work with the `phone_number` of the `tell` model, you can work with [**`.values_list(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), and work with:

```
phones = student.objects.values_list('phone_number__phone_number', flat=True)
for phone in phones:
    print(phone)
```

but this are thus *not* `tell` objects, and thus updating, refrehing, a record is not possible in that case.

Comment: I used value() because i want only the phone_number field.

Comment: @namjoo.org: in that case you can work with `.only()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) to boost performance, but you should not erode the model layer, especially since it then works with scalar values (or dictionaries), and thus all Django's meta logic no longer is in place.

Comment: I want to use student object not tell for query.

Comment: @namjoo.org: the last two code samples query the `student` model, for the first one we piggyback on the query to fetch all the related `tell` data with the same query.

Comment: @namjoo.org: and for the last one with the `.values_list(...)` we even simply retrieve the `phone_number` of the related `tell` model, but usually it is *not* a good idea to make use of `.values()`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html