# How to get the value of the foreign key field and count or other aggregation operations?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models. How can i count and show results like below:

Male   235

Female 240

Other  10

My models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
   name =   models.CharField(max_length = 200)  
   gender =   models.ForeignKey(gender, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank=True)
        
   def __str__(self):
      return '%s' % (self.name)
        
            
class Gender(models.Model):
    title=   models.CharField(max_length = 200)  
  
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

My views.py

```
def viewlist(request):  
    mylist = student.objects.values('gender').annotate(total=Count('gender')).order_by('-total')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Count

gender.objects.annotate(
    nstudents=Count('student')
).order_by('-nstudents')
```

This will for each `gender` in the table, annotate the object with the number of students `.nstudents`. If you thus enumerate over the `gender`s, then for each `gender` you can retrieve its `.nstudents` attribute which is the number of *related* students.

If there is a gender with *no* related `Student`s, then this gender will still show up in the results, since Django will work with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

If you pass this to your view, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.shortcuts import render

def some_view(request):
    genders = gender.objects.annotate(
        nstudents=Count('student')
    ).order_by('-nstudents')
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'genders': genders})</code></pre>
```

you can render the number of students with:

```
{% for gender in genders %}
    {{ gender }}: {{ gender.nstudents }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`gender`</s> to `Gender`.

Comment: This shows all gender values with their repetition.     mylist = student.objects.list_values('gender').annotate(total=Count('gender')).order_by('-total')
is this wrong?

Comment: @namjoo.org: it will not even show `gender`s for which there are no students. But more importantly this is an example of the [*primitive obsession* antipattern](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

Comment: By working with `gender.objects.annotate(...)` we simply retrieve each `gender` object (that can contain a name, but also a description, references, etc.) with an extra attribute per `gender`: we can fetch the number of students of that gender with `for mygender in data: print((mygender.title, mygender.nstudents))` so we actually still have the model logical layer, but with extra "tooling".

Comment: This example is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738649/how-to-get-value-of-foreignkey-in-views-py that you answerd me.

Comment: Can use student.objects.values_list ?

Comment: @namjoo.org: exactly, in essence it is the same problem. By using simple dictionaries, lists, strings, etc. you you end up with data without the logic defined in the original model. That is what makes the primitive obsession antipattern such a problem: it duplicates logic, and the data has no longer validation and/or behavior attached to it.[

Comment: @namjoo.org: making a query with `student` is simply wrong. Imagine that you have a gender without any related students, then you can not count that gender. Your view focusses on the gender (and number of students per gender), not on students.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, one should only use `.values` and `.values_list` if you want to perform an aggregation that is *not* done for a *per some model* base.

Comment: But i don't want to count gender. I want to count gender that students have selected them. if gender is not selected i don't count it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235894/discussion-between-namjoo-org-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: @namjoo.org: the idea is that you count items for a certain model, you thus will perform a `GROUP BY` that model, and thus that means that you should use that as the "root" model of your query.

Comment: @namjoo.org: if you do not want to count with genders for which there are no students, you simply filter these out with `gender.objects.filter(student__isnull=False).annotate(nstudents=Count('student'))`. But here the GROUP BY is the gender, not the student, hence that is the "active" model.

Comment: @namjoo.org: imagine that you have to implement this for an SQL query, then the most common way to do that is `SELECT gender.*, COUNT(student.id) FROM gender LEFT OUTER JOIN student ON student.gender_id = gender.id GROUP BY gender.id`, so since we use a `GROUP BY`, that means that this is the "root model".